# Custom GitHub Pages source

Tags: github, github-pages

I have `coverage/index.html` in my repo, and I'd like to add this as Source of my GitHub Pages. But this page will change as my coverage report changes, so I want to reference the one on the `master` branch, not use `gh-pages`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can configure the publishing source, switching between `master`, `gh-pages`, or `/docs`.

You can find out how to do it [here](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages/).

Comment: No, I meant, I want to use the `master` branch but say use `some-other-folder` as the root

Comment: Ok my bad I misunderstood